# Differences in %ALLUSERSPROFILE% in Windows XP and Vista+

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-xp, windows-vista

Is there an environment variable in Windows that indicates the folder to store application data that is shared by all users?

In Windows Vista and later, this is `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` (typically maps to `C:/ProgramData`). However in Windows XP, `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` maps to `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users` and I would still need to add something like `\Program Data\` to get to the equivalent location.

Comment: Not entirely helpful in solving your particular problem, but the pragmatic solution would be to ask your customers to upgrade to a supported version of the OS.

Comment: Please add a language tag so we know which language you are programming in.

Comment: @Anders The question is not language-specific. I am aware there are APIs to achieve the same thing without resorting to environment vars, but I specifically wanted to know about environment vars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a good solution for batch-files but I can explain the history.

On Windows 2000/XP/2003 `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` is exactly what its name is, the root of the all-users/shared/common profile directory. Typically "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users".

The Windows shell has a special folder constant called [CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) and it typically resolves to "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data" but there is unfortunately no environment variable set for this path on these systems.

In Windows Vista and later the documents, music and video folders were moved out of the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` folder and placed in a new folder called Public ("c:\Users\Public") and can be found with `%PUBLIC%`. CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA also got a environment variable called `%ProgramData%` and because most of the other folders moved to `%PUBLIC%` it was decided that `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` did not need the Application Data subfolder so `%ProgramData%` is the same as `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`.

If you are writing a batch-file:

My suggestion is, use `%ProgramData%` if it exists, otherwise, fall back to `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data`. I don't know if the Application Data folder has a different name on localized versions of Windows...

If you are writing a C/C++ application:

Use [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you are writing a .NET application:

Use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't have an XP box to check against, but I think `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data` should work in either case.  (On Vista and later there is a symlink named Application Data in the ProgramData folder.)  I'm not sure about localization though.

Comment: (Of course the *correct* solution is to use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`, environment variables are a legacy technology.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Correct, environment variables should not be used in Windows programs but the question is not tagged with a language so I assumed this was a batch-file question and there you are stuck with them unless you want to add some fragile registry reading code to your batch-file.

Comment: Oh, I'm not objecting to your answering, or to your answer.  And it is definitely safer to look at the environment variables than to read values from the registry.  I just realized that nobody had mentioned yet that, depending on context, environment variables might not be the sensible thing to do in the first place. :-)    (I was tempted to argue that manipulating the common application data folder from a batch file wasn't sensible either, but then I realized that I do the same thing myself, in some of my in-house code.  Oops!)